# How to place list items that are overlapping next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a schedule page were you can view a set schedule, the only problem now is when multiple list items are overlapping each others, i.e starting before item before is ending, you will see in my example:

```css
.day_div ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.day_div li,
#info_holder li {
    position: relative;
    /* background-color: red; */
    color: white;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);

    border-radius: 5px;
}

.day_div li::after,
#info_holder li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    /* z-index: -1; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out; */
}

.day_div li.no-after::after,
#info_holder li.no-after::after {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.day_div li::before {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.day_div li:hover.rotatable {
    /* transform: scale(0.9) rotate(6deg); */
    transform: rotate(6deg);
}


/* .day_div li:hover::after {
      opacity: 1;
    } */

/* skipping 1st child as it is the timeline */
.day_div li {
    background: rgb(60, 225, 226);
    background: linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(60, 225, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 55, 172, 1) 100%);
}

.day_div:nth-child(3) li,
#info_holder li.three {
    background: rgb(60, 226, 124);
    background: linear-gradient(340deg, rgba(60, 226, 124, 1) 0%, rgba(88, 124, 147, 1) 100%);
}

.day_div:nth-child(4) li,
#info_holder li.four {
    background: rgb(122, 168, 91);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(122, 168, 91, 1) 0%, rgba(108, 126, 121, 1) 100%);
}

.day_div:nth-child(5) li,
#info_holder li.five {
    background: rgb(246, 176, 101);
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, rgba(246, 176, 101, 1) 0%, rgba(246, 127, 101, 1) 100%);
}

.day_div:nth-child(6) li,
#info_holder li.six {
    background: rgb(156, 87, 151);
    background: linear-gradient(25deg, rgba(156, 87, 151, 1) 0%, rgba(67, 51, 82, 1) 100%);
}

.day_div:nth-child(7) li,
#info_holder li.seben {
    background: rgb(122, 168, 91);
    background: linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(122, 168, 91, 1) 0%, rgba(108, 126, 121, 1) 100%);
}

.day_div:nth-child(8) li,
#info_holder li.eight {
    background: rgb(60, 226, 124);
    background: linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(60, 226, 124, 1) 0%, rgba(88, 124, 147, 1) 100%);
}

.day_div li a,
#info_holder li a {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 100%;
      height: 100%; */
    padding: calc(0.75* 1.25em);
}

.day_div li div,
#info_holder li div {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: calc(0.75*1rem);
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 60%;
}

.day_div li a em,
#info_holder li a em {
    font-size: calc(var(--main-text-size)*0.8);
}

.day_div li.content_cutoff a::before,
#info_holder li.content_cutoff a::before {
    display: inline-block;
}

.day_div li a::before,
#info_holder li a::before {
    content: attr(data-start) " - "attr(data-end);
    display: block;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: calc(var(--main-text-size)*0.9);
}

.day_div li a.databefore::before,
#info_holder li a.databefore::before {
    content: attr(data-before);
}

.day_div li a em,
#info_holder li a em {
    font-size: calc(var(--main-text-size)*1.2);
}

.day_div:not(:first-child):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    border-left: none;
}

.day_div:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.day_div {
    /* may change to be a 5th of parent */
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    width: 16%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.day_div span {
    /* this is the day text styling */
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<div class="day_div">
    <!-- monday -->
    <span style="height: 50px; width: 238px;">Måndag</span>
    <ul style="margin-block-start: 25px;">
        <li data-overlappers="0" data-overlapping="0" class="rotatable" style="top: 25px; height: 100px;"><a data-start="08:00" data-end="09:00"><em>Matte</em></a><a data-before="Lärare" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(110px + 0.9375em);"><em>Göran</em></a><a data-before="Klassrum" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(189px + 0.9375em);"><em>Katedralen</em></a><a data-before="Inställd?" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(307px + 0.9375em);"><em>Ja</em></a>
            <div data-fade_invert="1" data-self_sized="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border-radius: 5px; display: block;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <metadata></metadata>
                    <g>
                        <title>background</title>
                        <rect fill="#00000050" id="canvas_background" height="500" width="500" y="0" x="0"></rect>
                        <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
                            <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <title>Layer 1</title>
                        <line stroke-dasharray="2,2" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_2" y2="500" x2="0" y1="0" x1="500" stroke-width="34" stroke="#000" fill="none"></line>
                    </g>
                </svg></div>
            <div style="opacity: 0; top: calc(72px + 0.46875em);"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></div>
        </li>
        <li data-overlappers="2" data-overlapping="0" class="rotatable" style="top: 41.6667px; height: 83.3333px;"><a data-start="09:10" data-end="10:00"><em>Spanska</em></a><a data-before="Lärare" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(110px + 0.9375em);"><em>Lisa &amp; Andy</em></a><a data-before="Klassrum" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(223px + 0.9375em);"><em>Katedralen</em></a><a data-before="Inställd?" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(341px + 0.9375em);"><em>Nej</em></a>
            <div data-fade_invert="1" data-self_sized="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border-radius: 5px; display: none;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <metadata></metadata>
                    <g>
                        <title>background</title>
                        <rect fill="#00000050" id="canvas_background" height="500" width="500" y="0" x="0"></rect>
                        <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
                            <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <title>Layer 1</title>
                        <line stroke-dasharray="2,2" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_2" y2="500" x2="0" y1="0" x1="500" stroke-width="34" stroke="#000" fill="none"></line>
                    </g>
                </svg></div>
            <div style="opacity: 0; top: calc(72px + 0.46875em);"><span></span></div>
        </li>
        <li data-overlappers="2" data-overlapping="1" class="rotatable" style="top: -41.6667px; height: 116.667px;"><a data-start="09:10" data-end="10:20"><em>Tyska</em></a><a data-before="Lärare" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(110px + 0.9375em);"><em>Mackan</em></a><a data-before="Klassrum" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(202px + 0.9375em);"><em>Akvariet</em></a><a data-before="Inställd?" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(297px + 0.9375em);"><em>Nej</em></a>
            <div data-fade_invert="1" data-self_sized="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border-radius: 5px; display: none;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <metadata></metadata>
                    <g>
                        <title>background</title>
                        <rect fill="#00000050" id="canvas_background" height="500" width="500" y="0" x="0"></rect>
                        <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
                            <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <title>Layer 1</title>
                        <line stroke-dasharray="2,2" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_2" y2="500" x2="0" y1="0" x1="500" stroke-width="34" stroke="#000" fill="none"></line>
                    </g>
                </svg></div>
            <div style="opacity: 0; top: calc(72px + 0.46875em);"><span>Presens som vanligt, glöm inte digilär</span></div>
        </li>
        <li data-overlappers="1" data-overlapping="2" class="rotatable" style="top: -141.667px; height: 83.3333px;"><a data-start="09:20" data-end="10:10"><em>Franska</em></a><a data-before="Lärare" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(110px + 0.9375em);"><em>Esma</em></a><a data-before="Klassrum" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(184px + 0.9375em);"><em>grupprummet</em></a><a data-before="Inställd?" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(327px + 0.9375em);"><em>Nej</em></a>
            <div data-fade_invert="1" data-self_sized="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border-radius: 5px; display: none;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <metadata></metadata>
                    <g>
                        <title>background</title>
                        <rect fill="#00000050" id="canvas_background" height="500" width="500" y="0" x="0"></rect>
                        <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
                            <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <title>Layer 1</title>
                        <line stroke-dasharray="2,2" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_2" y2="500" x2="0" y1="0" x1="500" stroke-width="34" stroke="#000" fill="none"></line>
                    </g>
                </svg></div>
            <div style="opacity: 0; top: calc(72px + 0.46875em);"><span></span></div>
        </li>
        <li data-overlappers="0" data-overlapping="2" class="rotatable" style="top: -158.333px; height: 300px;"><a data-start="10:00" data-end="13:00"><em>Lunch</em></a><a data-before="Lärare" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(110px + 0.9375em);"><em></em></a><a data-before="Klassrum" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(181px + 0.9375em);"><em></em></a><a data-before="Inställd?" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(271px + 0.9375em);"><em>Nej</em></a>
            <div data-fade_invert="1" data-self_sized="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border-radius: 5px; display: none;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <metadata></metadata>
                    <g>
                        <title>background</title>
                        <rect fill="#00000050" id="canvas_background" height="500" width="500" y="0" x="0"></rect>
                        <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
                            <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <title>Layer 1</title>
                        <line stroke-dasharray="2,2" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_2" y2="500" x2="0" y1="0" x1="500" stroke-width="34" stroke="#000" fill="none"></line>
                    </g>
                </svg></div>
            <div style="opacity: 0; top: calc(72px + 0.46875em);"><span></span></div>
        </li>
        <li data-overlappers="0" data-overlapping="0" class="rotatable" style="top: -158.333px; height: 200px;"><a data-start="13:00" data-end="15:00"><em>Mentorstid</em></a><a data-before="Lärare" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(117px + 0.9375em);"><em>Patrik</em></a><a data-before="Klassrum" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(194px + 0.9375em);"><em>Katedralen</em></a><a data-before="Inställd?" class="databefore" style="opacity: 0; left: calc(312px + 0.9375em);"><em>Nej</em></a>
            <div data-fade_invert="1" data-self_sized="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border-radius: 5px; display: none;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <metadata></metadata>
                    <g>
                        <title>background</title>
                        <rect fill="#00000050" id="canvas_background" height="500" width="500" y="0" x="0"></rect>
                        <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
                            <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <title>Layer 1</title>
                        <line stroke-dasharray="2,2" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_2" y2="500" x2="0" y1="0" x1="500" stroke-width="34" stroke="#000" fill="none"></line>
                    </g>
                </svg></div>
            <div style="opacity: 0; top: calc(72px + 0.46875em);"><span>Ta med datorer och inlämmningslapp</span></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see for 'spanska', 'tyska', 'franska' and 'lunch' are in some way overlapping each others. I want to achieve this:

[image: Schedule example]

Here is the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Snakehater/6dk84n1y/6/)

EDIT 1:

As this code above is just a part of the entire page that I am working on, I couldn't get everything in. Here is a screenshot from the page showing why the list elements need to have a fixed y position: to match the timeline on the left.

[image: Timeline etc]

Answers could be only css, javascript or both, doesn't matter for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution now was to add javascript that checks which elements that were overlapping and how many each element was overlapping. If an element was overlapping 4 other elements, it would be 1/4 of the width of the ul. Then I loop through again and check if each element is overlapping and then move that element to the left if that is true. If not, check next element.

This will first reduce the width of each element to make them fit, then move each element to the left if it is overlapping so it doesn't overlap the other elements.

When all this is done I let each element grow on the width as long as it doesn't overlap any elements so that no empty space is showing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question, but the reason you're experiencing vertical overlap is the `position: relative;` on the `<li>` for these items (ie. removing this will properly stack them, but it may be there for another purpose I'm not aware of). Secondly, you're not stacking horizontally because your `<ul>` is limited to the width of the containing `<div>` that has a width of 16% on it.

I would give the `<div>` the full width of space you want your content to use, give the `<ul>` 100% and then put the width restriction on the `<li>`.

Comment: The thing is that I have to have a fixed y position on all list elements because of the timeline I forgot to add to the question, check for an updated picture of that. I want the width of the ```<ul>``` to remain fixed but the list elements should vary in width so that all list elements are fitting without overlapping. The thing I want is the image that I draw, elements that normally overlap to be side by side and not on top of each other like it is now.

Comment: As you can see @Faye in the drawing I made, I don't want the elements to be above or under each others, I want them to be next to each other.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. As long as your ul is only 16% wide, your items aren't going to sit next to each other. If you're wanting to make sure they fit, I would suggest using flexbox css.

Comment: Okey, yes, thank you, I am working on a solution that seems promising, I will post it here when I am done.